# Minimum number of cuts required to divide a cube into $8$ equal parts

Tags: puzzle, cross-sections

A cube is to be cut into 8 pieces of equal size and shape. Here, each cut should be
straight and it should not stop till it reaches the other end of the cube.
The minimum number of such cuts required is

According to me, the first cut divides the cube into 2 equal pieces. The second cut divides it into 4 equal pieces, the third cut into 6 pieces of unequal sizes and the fourth cut into 8 equal pieces.

I don't understand how the third cut could give 8 pieces of equal size and shape.

Comment: Why did you do a third cut into 6 uneven pieces?  Why didn't you just do a third cut into $8$ even pieces?  First cut: cut the top face into two rectangles and cut through.  Second cut: The top face is two rectangles. Turn the knive 90 degrees and cut the two rectangles into four squares.  Third cut:  Look at a side face.  It has been cut into two rectangles either from the first or second cut.  Turn the knife so it parallel to the floor and cut those two rectangles into four squares and cut through.  The cube has now been divided into eight equal cubes.

Comment: Here's an image of a cube cut into eight pieces with three cuts.  https://df0b18phdhzpx.cloudfront.net/ckeditor_assets/pictures/1762090/original_Screenshot_2022-09-16_183953.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine the cube placed in front of you on a table.

The first two cuts are vertically down, $+$. This gives us $4$ equal pieces. The third cut is horizontal, like slicing the cube into two layers. Each of the $4$ pieces we had earlier is cut into two equal halves, giving us $8$ equal pieces.